# I am getting method not found error in Javascript. But I have defined it

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have in my web part `.ascx` file:

```
var _SVR = BellMedia.videoCarousel.videoHub({
    containerDiv: "carousel-<%= this.InstanceGuid %>",
    templateDiv: "small-video-rotator",
});
```

And this is what i have in the `bellmedia.videoCarousel.videoHub.js`:

```
var BellMedia = BellMedia || {};
BellMedia.namespace('BellMedia.videoCarousel');

(function ($, _, utils) {
    BellMedia.videoCarousel.videoHub = function (options) {
        var intInterval = 0,
        isPlayerReady = false,
        //MORE CODE HERE
    }        
    };
})(jQuery, _, BellMedia.bravo.utils);
```

I included `bellmedia.videoCarousel.videoHub.js` in the web part file.

And as you can see, the `videoHub` function is defined. But I am still getting the "videoHub" method not found message in Chrome Developer Tool Bar.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the underscore for when passed as the second function argument?

Comment: underscore.js, maybe?

Comment: Obvious maybe, but just to be sure, Did you include bellmedia.videoCarousel.videoHub.js *before* you use it? Also, the BellMedia.videoCarousel.videoHub function won't be available unless the anonymous function it is wrapped in has been executed first. Do you define BellMedia.videoCarousel before you define BellMedia.videoCarousel.videoHub?

Comment: yes, i include bellmedia.videoCarousel.videoHub.js  before i use it

Comment: what is underscore.js? what i am not quite clear is what does (jquery, _, BellMedia.bravo.utils) mean when you put in an underscore in the parameter? Please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my problem was resolved by including the underscore.js file

Answer (score 0):

You were possibly getting that error because of extra parentheses/curly-braces in your code. I checked and edited a snippet a bit using TextWrangler to balance them out. Check if this helps at all...

```
var BellMedia = BellMedia || {};
BellMedia.namespace('BellMedia.videoCarousel');
(function ($, _, utils) {

    BellMedia.videoCarousel.videoHub = function (options) {
        var intInterval = 0,
        isPlayerReady = false,
        //MORE CODE HERE
    };

})(jQuery, _, BellMedia.bravo.utils);
```